# Strange entanglement between two UITableViews in XCode5

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, storyboard, xcode5

*SUMMARY BEFORE EXPLANATION*

It’s as if the storyboard is treating the Tables as pointers to a single instance, simply because I copied and pasted through the storyboard. I am recording this here in part as a reminder to myself (I am an avid user of Stack Overflow) and as a warning to others. And of course, I want to know if there is a simple way of truly disentangling the two without having to recreate one of the ViewControllers from scratch. **please, read on for explanation.**

*BACK STORY*

First I created CatUIViewController using the storyboard. I completed the whole thing along with `.h` and `.m` files. Then, needing a similar ViewController for Dogs, I dragged and dropped an empty ViewController onto the storyboard from Object Library, and then I copied and pasted the entire UITableView from CatUIViewController to DogUIViewController. Then of course I did the same with the `.h` and `.m` files. Really the only difference between CatUIViewController and DogUIViewController is that Cat has two buttons in it’s header while dog has an UIImageView, along with other data that both headers share.

Naturally, Xcode does all the connections for me the moment I pasted into the Dog equivalents. It wired all the IBOutlets and IBActions automatically: a nice feature of Xcode.

*FURTHER DETAIL*

Both table views have a background image. And navigation from Cat to Dog is possible because my app is using UITabBar — no other linking exists between the two. Furthermore, while Cat leads its Tab, Dog is way down the line in its Tab’s NavigationController.

*THE PROBLEM*

The problem is this: If I am in DogUIViewController and click the tab to transition to CatUIViewController, after the transition the background of DogUIViewController shows up as the background of CatUIViewController. In fact, if I visit DogUIViewController and then navigate to any other page so ever… the second I click on the Tab for CatUIViewController, mysteriously it first shows the data for DogUIViewController before switching to the correct data about 1 second later. Another strangeness is that the converse is equally true.

I have been investigating the code to see what might be the cause and so far I have found nothing. It’s as if the entanglement is happening at a layer in Xcode that is not exposed to me: I review the Connections Inspector, the `.h` and `.m` files and I cannot find anything so far. I am hoping it is a simple oversight on my part so I keep digging. But just in case it is not and someone else has resolved something similar, I am here asking.

Comment: What a veritably beautiful way to ask a question. Too bad the answer may not do you any good. It's looking like this is a storyboard bug, and there are many such bugs. Anyway, nice reading.

Comment: You can control or right click on the starboard in Xcode and display it as "source" - This will show the underlying XML document and may allow you to see if there is something there that shouldn't be

Comment: @Paulw11 is there something in particular I should be looking for? Nothing jumps at me. All the ids so far are different.

Comment: There is nothing magic about how storyboards work - When you instantiate a VC the appropriate chunk is passed to the `initWithCoder` method, so if you can't see any reference to "Cat" objects in your "Dog" scene then your problem is probably corruption in your view controller hierarchy at run time - If you manipulate the tab bar's vc properties directly look closely at that code.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas you copied and pasted not only the UITableView but also both the `.h` and the `.m` file, the possibility for errors abounds. But of particular interest to me is that you mention differences to exist exclusively in the header files. This to me means the likely cause of errors is your data source. Wherever you are fetching the data, it takes a split second so that the new data is delayed just enough for the old data to show up. So I am ending my response with a question: How are you fetching your data? Are you caching the data? Are you cleaning property? For example, if you are using notification for the server to update your view controllers, viewDidUnload is deprecated so I wouldn't use that to unregister notificatoins. In whatever the case, you at your data source.

Comment: My data source was indeed being shared. It's the same service call, but with different parameters. Yep. This was a big one.